# Развернуть дамп базы при сборке docker контейнера

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Долго искал, ответов уйма, ничего не помогает... Имеется следующий `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php7
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  php7:
    build: ./docker/php7
    ports:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    environment: 
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.50.75 #Подставить свой удаленный IP
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test200
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  db:
    container_name: test200
    build: ./docker/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test200
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

В докерфайле для mysql одна строчка: `FROM mysql:latest`

в папке dumps которая линкуется с контейнером лежит простой sql файл:

```
create database test;
use test;

CREATE TABLE testtab
(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
name TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT='this is my test table';
```

В общем проблема в том, что после запуска `docker-compose up -d --build` не созадётся новая тестовая БД с тестовой таблицей... Перед каждой проверкой удалял собранные контейнеры `docker-compose rm -f`. Прошу помощи

**Upd:** Вот ссылка на доку данной фичи https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ (ближе к низу страницы подзаголовок **Initializing a fresh instance**)

Comment: а command пробовали  ?

Comment: Конечно, это необычно, но вы пробовали прописать `./docker/mysql/dumps/mysql.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql.sql` ?

Comment: Проверил - не работает(

Comment: В сявзи с некоторыми сложностями поднятия MySQL (у вас должно быть запущено более одного процесса) это очень сложно сделать, и я рекомендую отказаться от этой затеи. Как вариант, вы можете запустить обычный контейнер, залить дамп обычными средствами, затем остановить и сделать commit, но через обычный Dockerfile это невозможно сделать без траты огромного количества человекоресурсов.

Comment: Конкретно с *"после запуска docker-compose up -d --build не созадётся"* дело скорее всего в том, что /var/lib/mysql уже существует, поэтому entrypoint не пытается проинициализирвоать БД еще раз.

Comment: @etki, спасибо, второй ваш коммент внес ясность и все получилось. Сделайте его ответом и я помечу как верным. Всё дело в этой линковке `- ./docker/mysql/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql` т.к. она уже содержала структуру